# DuplicateFile table with GAC

Tags: gac, installshield

My installer has grown very large b/c of file duplication. Some of our DLL's are in two places (local and GAC or local and system32 folders). How can I use the DuplicateFile table or other Installshield mechanism (installscript?) to duplicate the file in the GAC? It's the same file that needs to be copied to two locations but I only want it in the installer once because of its size.

My project type is actually Installscript MSI.

Hopefully my request is clear. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't understood that `"to duplicate the file in the GAC"` part; Can you please rephrase it?

Comment: I would like to take a local assembly in the \bin folder and then use installshield or MSI functionality to copy the file into the C:\Windows\assembly folder.  The DuplicateFile table doesn't seem to work for this (as the physical *.dll isn't located in the \assembly folder). Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DuplicateFile table doesn't support deploying to the GAC because MSI doesn't uses a different pattern to deploy to the GAC then most folders.  It uses MsiPlublishAssemblies which interacts with Fusion.

You have to declare 2 components ( 1 for normal and 1 for the GAC ).  If size is a concern for you,  WiX has a feature called smart cabbing which can create your cab and stream it into media with multiple file rows sharing the same storage.